# AngularJS ScopeLive Update with set interval

Tags: angularjs

I'm not able to view periodical live updates.

```
   $scope.items = [
          { Label: 'Personal', Num: "42" },
          { Label: 'Capital', Num: "10" }
        ];
        setInterval(function () {
            $scope.items.push({Label: 'Stock', Num: "62"});
        }, 2000);
```

what am I missing? `$scope.$wath(...)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  setInterval(function () {
      $scope.$apply( function() {
         $scope.items.push({Label: 'Stock', Num: "62"});
      });
  }, 2000);
```

or you can use angular `$interval` service ( **recommended** )

Link : [Angular $interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Comment: Thank you @Andy Ecca : I would like to accept this answer but please provide me with an example using `$interval`